not able to run karate feature file
I am using jdk 17 and karate core 1.4.1 dependencies in my maven project
While running a feature file in karate getting error message

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"javax.script.ScriptEngine.createBindings()" because
"com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.NASHORN" is null

I tried by changing dependencies of karate but it did not work

the ONLY way you can get help is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
